# making two columns responsive in html

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Simple one probably. I've made a webpage and now need it to be responsive to a mobile at 375px;

In the html I have added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

My two columns are named in the html as follows:

```css
#columnleft {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E8F8F5;
}

#columnright {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F4ECF7;
}
```

```html
<div id="columnleft"> ..... </div>
<div id="columnright"> ..... </div>
```

I know i need to make a media query like this

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 375 px)
```

But nothing is working. The largest size is 1024 px only these two sizes matter for this project. Nothing in between. I need the two columns to stack up on top of each other rather than side by side

Any advice much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Remove the space between `375 px`

Comment: remove the floats from your column css and display inline-block

Answer (score 1):

make their width 100%

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 357px) {
  #columnleft, #columnright {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! This doesn't work though, should I remove the 50% width from my columns ?

Comment: i put the max width 357px, change it to 375px
the 50% shouldn't affect them when you change the size to 375px if the media query works. 
make sure that you only use the id once in the body

Comment: ahh, so I've used the div id twice in the body, once to define the left column and again to define the right column

Comment: yes that's right, but don't use the same id twice. ex: two different divs have the columnleft id.

Comment: I've posted the code above with the two divs, what could i change them too?