# How to make columns responsive in html

Tags: html

Simple one probably. I've made a webpage and now need it to be responsive to a mobile at 375px;

In the html I have added:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

My two columns are named in the css as follows:

```
 #columnleft {
  float: left;
 width: 50%;
   text-align: center;
  background-color: #E8F8F5;
 }

 #columnright {
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #F4ECF7;
 }
```

Inside my html, the columns are sectioned as follows: where the dots represent content

```
  <div id="columnleft"> ..... </div>
  <div id="columnright"> ..... </div>
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work? Can anyone suggest why?

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
 #columnleft, #columnright {
  width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

I have also tried removing the float left and float right from the css

Comment: i highly suggest using a framework

Comment: Like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: @PhilippSander  for the purpose of this project i can only use html and css, I'm not sure what those are you suggested are

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Your CSS works as intended. Resize the result window: https://jsfiddle.net/j4u5gmfv/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a duplicate of your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354449/making-two-columns-responsive-in-html

Comment: @Turnip i fixed that. thanks. still not luck though :/

Comment: @Rob hi Rob, sorry, I'm not sure how to use stack that well. I tried to delete my previous as I made some mistakes, I just thought it would be easier to make a new one. It did not let me delete though

Comment: That was a "note", not a solution. No HTML tag uses a closing slash.

Comment: @Nicole Fixed what? Your code works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/j4u5gmfv/. You need to create a [MRE] within your question. There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown us.

Comment: There should be an edit and delete button somewhere on your page to do both and either.

Comment: @Turnip wow it works fine on that link. so strange! Is it maybe what I have inside each div column? The left contains just a form, and the right contains some words inside <p> that's literally it

Comment: No idea. This is why you need to provide a [MRE] clearly showing the issue.

Comment: @turnip ah right sorry, I wasn't sure. I've added the two div elements to my question above

Comment: @turnip i tested that code in the link you sent and the columns dont stack

Comment: _"wow it works fine on that link. so strange!"_ ?? I keep asking you to provide a MRE. This should be _all of the code_ needed to reproduce the issue. One complete example that we can test. Not lots of snippets of code dumped in your question. Use JSFiddle or a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) within your question.

Comment: @Turnip hi turnip. Sorry I'm new to this. Do you think I could just post all of my html and css code above for you to have a look? Really struggling with this as I can't see where the problem is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Okay a way to do this using just html and css flexbox would be

```
.row{
  display:flex;
}

#columnleft, #columnright {
  width:50%;
  padding:1rem;
}

#columnleft {
  background-color: #E8F8F5; 
 }

 #columnright {
 background-color: #F4ECF7;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
 #columnleft, #columnright {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
   }
 }


<div class="row">
  <div id="columnleft">...</div>
  <div id="columnright">... </div>
</div>
```

I actually tried it using the code you initially wrote though and it seems fine.

Comment: hi, I've not got row in there, I'll try that now

Comment: strange, I've copied your exact code and it does not work :/ so confusing

Comment: Can you perhaps share a screenshot of what you get on mobile please

Comment: yes tho it is not letting me post the screenshot or edit the question. The two rows are just squashed together rather than on top of one another

Answer (score 0):

I test your code it work well, may be problem you set `@media` before your css for desktop.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 
  
  <style>
   #columnleft {
  float: left;
 width: 50%;
   text-align: center;
  background-color: #E8F8F5;
 }

 #columnright {
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #F4ECF7;
 }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
 #columnleft, #columnright {
  width: 100%;
   }
 }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="columnleft"> LEFT </div>
  <div id="columnright"> RIGHT </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: huh! I'm not sure why its not working for me. I see you've got style in the HTML, do you think it should still work if it is in the css?